# How can I select combinations of levels in a pandas Multindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
                                   names=['one', 'two', 'three'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(18, 3), index=index)

            0           1           2
one two three           
1   a   b   0.002568    0.390393    0.040717
        c   0.943853    0.105594    0.738587
    b   b   0.049197    0.500431    0.001677
        c   0.615704    0.051979    0.191894
2   a   b   0.748473    0.479230    0.042476
        c   0.691627    0.898222    0.252423
    b   b   0.270330    0.909611    0.085801
        c   0.913392    0.519698    0.451158
```

I want to select rows where combination of index levels `two` and `three` are `(a, b)` or `(b, c)`.  How can I do this?

I tried `df.loc[(slice(None), ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c']), :]` but that gives me all combinations of `[a, b]` and `[b, c]`, including `(a, c)` and `(b, b)`, which aren't needed.

I tried `df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(None, 'a', 'b'), (None, 'b', 'c')])]` but that returns `NaN` in level `one` of the index.

```
df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(None, 'a', 'b'), (None, 'b', 'c')])]

            0   1   2
NaN a   b   NaN NaN NaN
    b   c   NaN NaN NaN
```

So I thought I needed a slice at level `one`, but that gives me a `TypeError`:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(slice(None), 'a', 'b'), (slice(None), 'b', 'c')])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

I feel like I'm missing some simple one-liner here :).

Comment: I see good pandas question. I up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [df.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [174]: df.query("(two=='a' and three=='b') or (two=='b' and three=='c')")
Out[174]:
                      0         1         2
one two three
1   a   b      0.211555  0.193317  0.623895
    b   c      0.685047  0.369135  0.899151
2   a   b      0.082099  0.555929  0.524365
    b   c      0.901859  0.068025  0.742212
```

**UPDATE:**  we can also generate such "query" dynamically:

```
In [185]: l = [('a','b'), ('b','c')]

In [186]: q = ' or '.join(["(two=='{}' and three=='{}')".format(x,y) for x,y in l])

In [187]: q
Out[187]: "(two=='a' and three=='b') or (two=='b' and three=='c')"

In [188]: df.query(q)
Out[188]:
                      0         1         2
one two three
1   a   b      0.211555  0.193317  0.623895
    b   c      0.685047  0.369135  0.899151
2   a   b      0.082099  0.555929  0.524365
    b   c      0.901859  0.068025  0.742212
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, for multi-index - only if they are named... ;-)

Comment: and, shouldn't conflict with column names.

Comment: A lazy `pd.concat([df.loc[(slice(None), ) + x, :] for x in [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]])` piece of code, there must be a better way to use multiple slices..

Comment: Thanks @MaxU!  Just baffled at the speed with which you replied :).  So the query works great for my minimal example.  I actually have many combinations to select.  Feels a bit clumsy to dynamically construct a long string query - are there also any "vectorized" methods?

Comment: @MaxU --  I know, hence I said lazy, wasn't sure how to use slices for multi

Comment: Random gotcha: in my real data, one of the index levels contains bytes (encoded strings), and `query()` barfs with `AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Bytes'`

Comment: @capitalistcuttle, my notebook’s battery is empty so I can only give you an idea now- construct another multi index and use df.loc[df.index.intersection(another_idx)] Note: another multiindex must have the same columns

Comment: @MaxU Ah, yes, that makes sense.  If you want to add that example when you're plugged in, then I'll mark the answer as accepted since there will be a couple of approaches shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach with `loc` and `get_level_values`

```
In [3231]: idx = df.index.get_level_values

In [3232]: df.loc[((idx('two') == 'a') & (idx('three') == 'b')) |
                  ((idx('two') == 'b') & (idx('three') == 'c'))]
Out[3232]:
                      0         1         2
one two three
1   a   b      0.442332  0.380669  0.832598
    b   c      0.458145  0.017310  0.068655
2   a   b      0.933427  0.148962  0.569479
    b   c      0.727993  0.172090  0.384461
```

Generic way

```
In [3262]: conds = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]

In [3263]: mask = np.column_stack(
                      [(idx('two') == c[0]) & (idx('three') == c[1]) for c in conds]
                    ).any(1)

In [3264]: df.loc[mask]
Out[3264]:
                      0         1         2
one two three
1   a   b      0.442332  0.380669  0.832598
    b   c      0.458145  0.017310  0.068655
2   a   b      0.933427  0.148962  0.569479
    b   c      0.727993  0.172090  0.384461
```